# Accepting the type of an array dynamically during runtime and later use the array to save the individual records

Tags: java, reflection

I am taking the class name as input from the user.
Now if the user gives the name "ClassA" then I need to create an array of type ClassA.
For example:
ClassA[] classAarray=assign something to the array.

Later each item in the array are saved in the database using jpa repository:

for(ClassA item:classAarray)
jparepository.save(item);

Maybe we can do this by using java reflection . Let me know if there is any example for this type of requirement .

Comment: use switch-case instead. java-reflection is slow.

Comment: If I use switch case then I need to change the code whenever there is new requirement.

Comment: use MyClass.class.toString() as switch argument